# Go: Is a class-based approach more performant than functional?

Tags: performance, class, go, functional-programming

I am curious if a class-based approach using structs and functions on those structs is more performant in Golang?

So far I have been unable to unearth any resources that compare the two different techniques.

This question came out of a conversation when I was told using a class-based approach to coding is more performant in Javascript than functional.

Comment: Go isn't a functional programming language *per se*. Golang supports first-class functions, see: https://blog.golang.org/first-class-functions-in-go-and-new-go . However, I don't think it will make any difference in performance – use first-class functions/recursion/etc. when it makes sense to use them.

Comment: Go methods are just functions, so there's no performance different calling one or the other.

Comment: *"I was told using a class-based approach to coding is more performant in Javascript than functional."* – ignore this kind of dribble. there's no way that's true for all possible programs. Use the style you want and optimize for performance when its required.

Comment: A note on the side, not related to performance, but to design. You can always satisfy a function type with a (bound) method, but in order to satisfy an interface you need a type with methods (though it can be a dummy struct{}). On the other hand interfaces are more expressive, of course. Look at the stdlib - utilities are mostly functions and methods are used sparingly, mostly as means to implement interfaces, and less often (than other languages) as utility. I don't think performance should be the guiding force for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually test this in go!

In your code you can create a method and the equivalent function. I'm doing this in a `main.go` file.

```
type A string
func (a A) Demo(i int) {}
func Demo(a A, i int) {}
```

Then create a benchmark for it in the test file (`main_test.go` for me).

```
func BenchmarkMethod(b *testing.B) {
    var a A = "test"
    var i int = 123

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        a.Demo(i)
    }
}

func BenchmarkFunction(b *testing.B) {
    var a A = "test"
    var i int = 123

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Demo(a, i)
    }
}
```

Then test the benchmarks with `go test -bench=.`

```
BenchmarkMethod-8       2000000000           0.27 ns/op
BenchmarkFunction-8     2000000000           0.29 ns/op
PASS
```

You can update your method and function to do the same thing to see how that affects things.

```
func (a A) Demo(i int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", a, i)
}

func Demo(a A, i int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%d", a, i)
}
```

And testing this still gets me nearly identical perf.

```
$ go test -bench=.
BenchmarkMethod-8       10000000           233 ns/op
BenchmarkFunction-8     10000000           232 ns/op
PASS
```

So short answer - I highly doubt there is any significant performance difference between the two, and if there is it looks like any other code you run is likely to have a larger impact than using methods vs functions.

Comment: at .27ns per op, your first benchmark is probably optimized away completely (or maybe that would be the point here, that it doesn't matter)

Comment: That is basically the point - if we can't tell any sort of noticeable difference in our benchmarks, chances are it isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: Very complete and succinct, just what I was looking for.